# Making a highlightable map divided by regions with Highchart (Angular + D3)

Tags: angular, d3.js, highcharts, highcharts-ng

I need to construct a map of my country - just the outline of the separate regions in solid, representative colors - and the tools I was offered were these. As someone with little experience in web development, I am overwhelmed.

How do I begin? How can I extract these shapes and use them in this manner?

Comment: You could start with reading a bit here: https://www.highcharts.com/maps/demo

Comment: This looks like a tutorial of what you want to do: https://www.highcharts.com/docs/maps/custom-maps

Comment: ..or just find your country here: http://code.highcharts.com/mapdata/ and click the "Demo" link.